Beta Israel Fetha Negest ፍትሐ ነገሥት (Law of Kings)?
The Beta Israel chachamim relay that the Ethiopian Epic Kebra Nagast ክብረ ነገሥት is of authentic origin but was "christianized" by the scribes of the mishrikist emperors and the Ethiopian Orthodox Church.
Is this also the case for the legal code Fetha Negest ፍትሐ ነገሥት? Does it originate from a Beta Israel kernel? Or is there another Beta Israel law of Kings?

Few members here know much of anything regarding the Ethiopian community. I recommend you direct your questions to Dr. Yosi Ziv, a renowned expert on their history and traditions. https://ric.org.il/researcher/yosi-ziv-2.

Thank you for recommending Dr. Ziv @Harel13!!! Why don't we recruit him here!

You're welcome to try, but I suspect he's busy with other things.
